# Как во Vue.js получать значение из input не используя v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, framework7

Есть такой пример. При нажатии на кнопку "**добавить заметку**" идёт проверка не пустой ли **input** и добавляется блок  с ведённым в **input** текстом. Как сделать этот же пример не используя **v-bind** так как он не работает в framework7?

Как взять значение из инпут во vue?

Пытался как-то так сделать но не работает

```
let getCat = document.getElementByClassName('inputCat').value;
let newCat = this.getCat;
this.cats.push(this.newCat);
this.newCat = '';
this.saveCats();
```

**Работающий пример с v-model**

```
  <f7-block v-for="(cat, n) in cats">
      <span class="cat">{{ cat }}</span>
      <f7-button fill color="red" @click="removeCat(n)">Удалить</f7-button>
  </f7-block>

    <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-input
          class="inputCat"
          v-model="newCat"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Заметка"
        ></f7-list-input>
        <f7-button fill color="blue" @click="addCat">Добавить заметку</f7-button>
    </f7-list>
```

```
export default {
data() {
    return{
        cats:[],
        newCat: null
  }
},
mounted() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('cats')) {
    try {
      this.cats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cats'));
    } catch(e) {
      localStorage.removeItem('cats');
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  addCat() {
    // убедиться, что было что-либо введено
    if (!this.newCat) {
      return;
    }
    this.cats.push(this.newCat);
    this.newCat = '';
    this.saveCats();
  },
  removeCat(x) {
    this.cats.splice(x, 1);
    this.saveCats();
  },
  saveCats() {
    const parsed = JSON.stringify(this.cats);
    localStorage.setItem('cats', parsed);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: А вы посмотрите ошибку в консоли, наверняка там `Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function`.

Comment: Тут всё решаеться этими двумя строчками.       `:value="newCat"
          @input="newCat = $event.target.value"`  Вот теперь бы понять как из самого инпут убрать выражение **newCat = $event.target.value** в сам код и оставить там только newCat

Answer (score 1):

`f7-list-input` не обычный `input`, а `div` с вложенным `input`

```
let getCat = document.querySelector('.inputCat input').value;
```